# How can I make time even faster in Escape Mode?

Tags: prison-architect

I tend to play on Escape Mode a lot so this is a really big issue but the fastest setting the game offers is still moderately slow. Is there any way to speed the game up more than the what the options there already do.

I'm playing on PC, on the Steam version.

Comment: To the VtC'ers: there are other possible ways to tweak an in-game setting besides recommending "games, servers, software, or hardware" (cheats, .ini tweaks, console commands). The OP is not asking for recommendations at all.

Comment: Ok yeah you have a point but the thing is, is there a way to speed up the time in Escape Mode further than the options already there?